# Pinned SliverPersistentHeader inside CustomScrollView scrolls behind another pinned SliverPersistentHeader inside NestedScrollView

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-sliver

**Background**

I have two `SliverPersistentHeaders`. One is located inside `NestedScrollView` and has a `TabBar` inside of it which should be always visible on scroll, so I made it pinned. Also I have another `SliverPersistentHeader` which is located inside `CustomScrollView` in one of the tabs. It should be always visible on scroll when this tab is opened, so I made it pinned also.

Here is what I have visually. The `SliverPersistentHeaders` I write about are white and blue:

https://ibb.co/JzZPyqp

**The Problem**

I expect both of the `SliverPersistentHeaders` to be pinned and not go up on scroll. But it turns out the `SliverPersistentHeader` inside `CustomScrollView` scrolls behind the `SliverPersistentHeader` in `NestedScrollView` and only then gets pinned like so:

https://s2.gifyu.com/images/untitled446dfde99b45261c.gif

**Let's jump to the code**

```java
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  var _tabController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _tabController = TabController(
      length: 2,
      vsync: this,
    );
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: NestedScrollView(
          physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
          floatHeaderSlivers: true,
          headerSliverBuilder: (context, value) {
            return [
              // here we have the first SliverPersistentHeader
              // with TabBar as content
              // inside of NestedScrollView
              SliverPersistentHeader(
                pinned: true,
                floating: false,
                delegate: _TabBarAsSliverPersistentHeader(_tabController),
              ),
            ];
          },
          body: 
              // BlocProvider might be here in the real project...
          CustomScrollView(
            slivers: [
              // here we have the second SliverPersistentHeader
              // inside of CustomScrollView
              // it has unexpected behaviour as shown in gif above
              SliverPersistentHeader(
                pinned: true,
                floating: false,
                delegate: PersistentHeaderDateFilter(),
              ),
              SliverList(
                delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                  (context, index) => Container(
                    height: 100,
                    margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                    color: Colors.red,
                    
                  ),
                  childCount: 10,
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class _TabBarAsSliverPersistentHeader extends SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate {
  final TabController _tabController;

  _TabBarAsSliverPersistentHeader(this._tabController);

  @override
  Widget build(
      BuildContext context, double shrinkOffset, bool overlapsContent) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return Container(
      // color: Theme.of(context).backgroundColor,
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          Positioned.fill(
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                border: Border(
                  bottom: BorderSide(
                    color: Theme.of(context).dividerColor,
                    width: 1.0,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            color: Colors.transparent,
            child: TabBar(
              
              isScrollable: false,
              indicator: UnderlineTabIndicator(
                borderSide: BorderSide(
                  width: 2,
                  color: Colors.blue,
                ),
              ),
              indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.tab,
              indicatorWeight: 2,
              labelColor: Colors.blue,
              unselectedLabelColor: Colors.grey,
              tabs: [
                Tab(text: 'by rating'),
                Tab(text: 'by date'),
              ],
              controller: _tabController,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  double get maxExtent => 46.0;

  @override
  double get minExtent => 46.0;

  @override
  bool shouldRebuild(covariant SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate oldDelegate) {
    return false;
  }
}

class PersistentHeaderDateFilter extends SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate {
  PersistentHeaderDateFilter();

  @override
  Widget build(
      BuildContext context, double shrinkOffset, bool overlapsContent) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return Container(
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
        vertical: 10,
      ),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.blue.shade200,
        border: Border(
          bottom: BorderSide(
            color: Colors.green,
            width: 1.0,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      child: ListView.builder(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
        // shrinkWrap: true,
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        itemCount: 10,
        // ignore: missing_return
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return Container(
              color: Colors.amber,
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(5),
              width: 50,
              child: Text(index.toString()),
            );
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  double get maxExtent => 110.0;

  @override
  double get minExtent => 110.0;

  @override
  bool shouldRebuild(covariant SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

**What I tried**

So far I have experimented with `SliverOverlapAbsorber` and `SliverOverlapInjector` which are mentioned in flutter doc of `NestedScrollView` but without any good results. Moving `TabBar` to `SliverAppBar` bottom property also was not successful.

Comment: Did you find anything?

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me:

I've wrapped the whole `SliverPersistentHeader (my _buildTabNavigation())` in `SliverOverlapAbsorver`:

```
 SliverOverlapAbsorber(
    handle: NestedScrollView.sliverOverlapAbsorberHandleFor(context),
    sliver: _buildTabNavigation(),
 ),
```

Doing this, your list will be stuck under the TabBar. Then you can wrap your `NestedScrollView` body in a Container and add a margin top.

Something like this:

```
return NestedScrollView(
      controller: _scrollController,
      headerSliverBuilder: (context, value) {
        return [
          SliverOverlapAbsorber(
            handle: NestedScrollView.sliverOverlapAbsorberHandleFor(context),
            sliver: _buildTabNavigation(),
          ),
        ];
      },
      body: Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 50),
        child: TabBarView(
          controller: _tabController,
          children: _tabs,
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

I had very similar problem with:

- NestedScrollView

  - SliverAppBar (pinned)
  - TabBarView

    - CustomScrollView

      - SliverPersistentHeader (pinned)
      - Main content

SliverPersistentHeader was scrolled and then pinned under SliverAppBar.
[SliverPinnedOverlapInjector](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/91972#issuecomment-995462622) together with SliverOverlapAbsorber helped.